# .Net Web API POST method response Chrome browser issue (Sitefinity CMS)

Tags: .net, ajax, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, sitefinity

Findings of a rather peculiar issue with  Web Api which returns the following error in the response body

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.Api.OData.Extensions.RequestMessageProperties.get_Service()\r\n
>   at
>   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.Api.OData.Filters.CorsPolicyAttribute.GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.d__10.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.d__0.MoveNext()"}

For those who doubt whether I am doing a CORS request, No I am not.

The web api post method gets completely executed except the return part where I return a class object with two properties "Status" and "Message" without serialization.

Some debugging:

1. The method works fine in firefox.
2. The method works in chrome if SSL is enabled.
3. The method works in a pure .Net project without Sitefinity.

Please revert, if you need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this in the latest version - 9.2 where I had registered a custom route of /api/ and it looks Sitefinity also is using that route and that caused such  errors.

I ended up disabling the built-in Web Services module (the new feature) from **Administration > Modules and Services** and also renaming my custom route to something else, e.g. /ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove Sitefinity's modules for your web api request. Add this code inside web.config and change the path to your request:

```
<location path="PATH TO YOUR API">
  <system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
       <remove name="Sitefinity"/>
       <remove name="SitefinityAnalyticsModule"/>
       <remove name="SitefinityAtompubModule"/>
       <remove name="RadUploadModule" />
       <remove name="RadCompression" />
     </modules>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: Will check and let you know @Victor